# MVC receive post from another website - Chrome says Post Cancelled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am posting via a plain html text file on `c:\` drive into my mvc website running on my machine:

```
<body>
<a id="testPost" href="./post_files/post.htm">test post</a>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#testPost").click(function () {
    $.post("http://hml.backend/Helix/Authorisation", 
    {
        ClientIP: "192.168.20.34"
    }, function (resultData) {
        alert(resultData);
    });

    return false;
});
```

the controller is setup thus:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authorisation(string ClientIP)
{
    string result = _videoSecurityService.CheckHelixAuthorisation(ClientIP);
    return Content(result);
}
```

The controller event gets hit in debug and there is no exception but Chrome says

> 'POST: Cancelled' in the debug window

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cross domain call and is not allowed in a lot of browsers, since it's a possible security risk. You could try to redirect your call on the server-side. (make the call to your own application and handle the request-response to the other website there)

Comment: Thanks, I thinks that's it. I've now instead tested the post with a windows forms app with code from: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-27